# How to make a model's column optional in rails5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a model(post) having two parents Community and User.
Now i want that It could be possible that `community_id` field may or maynot be filled so i run a migration stating `change_column_null` and `change_column_default` for `community_id` 's null to be allowed and default value to be zero

Now error is that community should exist so should i create a community of `id=0` in rails console,is it a good practice?

or Am I doing something wrong in following code below,in allowing null true???

Post.rb(model)

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :community
end
```

migration:

```
class Postcommunityidallownull < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    change_column_null :posts, :community_id, true
    change_column_default :posts,:community_id, 0
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want an optional `belongs_to`:

1) Just don't add in the field's migration

```
null: false
```

2) In the model use

```
belongs_to :community, optional: true
```

Comment: thnx,But i m working on someone elses code.
How to update the table now. I want to do it properly ,else  my code above is still working fine

Comment: `community_id` should be `null` not 0, if it's indeed optional. If you add `optional: true` to your model, it will only apply to future records. To alter existing ones, you need a migration. `change_column_default(:posts, :community_id, nil)` should do the trick.

Comment: My pleasure Sir ;)